# type="number" to type="text" and add class in ActiveAdmin (globally)

Tags: activeadmin

I have tables with fields with type `numeric(12,2)`.

ActiveAdmin (with help of formastic gem) renders them as `type="number"`.

I want it to render them as `type="text"` and add class `float-field`. Is it possible to do it globally? I'm not against of monkey-patching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to monkeypatch Formastic gem:

```ruby
module Formtastic
  module Inputs
    class NumberInput
      include Base
      include Base::Stringish
      include Base::Placeholder

      def to_html
        input_wrapping do
          label_html << builder.text_field(method, input_html_options.merge(class: 'float-field'))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Active Admin builds on Formtastic. The Fomtastic README documents [Modified & Custom Inputs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs). You would implement an apps/inputs/float_input and reference it as `f.input :total, as: :float`